# Turn elasticsearch _search?q=<query> into query_string_query

Tags: elasticsearch

Given a query for the [_search API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html)'s `q` field one can run a lucene query against Elasticsearch. When the same query is run through the Query DSL's [query_string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) or [simple_query_string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-simple-query-string-query.html) the returned results are not always in correspondence. More specifically a search for

```
"Cannot get property 'code' on null object"~0
```

returns results through `q` but doesn't through `query_string` or `simple_query_string`.

Reading the `query_string` documentation I understand that slop might need to be specified as

```
{"query": "\"Cannot get property 'code' on null object\"", "phrase_slop":0}
```

which doesn't work either. Trying to remove the quotes and change the analyzer

```
{"query": "Cannot get property 'code' on null object", "phrase_slop":0, "analyzer":"keyword"}
```

doesn't work either. Setting the default_field didn't help either. The list goes on.

Trying `simple_query_string` which seems closer to what `q` does based on the documentation didn't solve the issue either.

---

#### The question

Is there some magic happening with the `q` URI parameter? How can one take that exact query and shove it into the Query DSL?

Comment: What's your mapping? What's the query? Sample docs?

Comment: Does any of that matter? Isn't this a purely mechanical exercise? The `q` query goes through some interpretation and I want to achieve the same interpretation in the Query DSL. Why is any of that input necessary for that task?

Comment: You've included error messages that originated from concrete queries. How do you expect generic answers? :)

Comment: No, I included a query that happened to be a query searching for a specific error message that was logged into elasticsearch. It is not an Elasticsearch error. The example's sole purpose was to show an example of a query that I'm struggling to port to the Query DSL. And I'll try to point it out again - I expected the porting to be a copy-paste, maybe with some static settings that need to be set within the Query DSL's query.

Comment: Do you get an error ? what is the error ? or are you not getting any result ? do you run it from curl ? kibana ?